# WordPress: Dynamic background images for each <section>

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm creating a page with 5 `<section>`s of content, each 720px in height.  I would like to have 5 different background images (i.e. one for each section), as well as the ability to change the image for a given section via WordPress administration.

I'm using CSS to set the background image for each section, e.g.:

```
.section-1 {
    position: relative;
    background: url("images/section-1-bg.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 720px;
}
```

I've looked at countless plugins and examples, but have yet to find anything remotely resembling to what I'm trying to do.  I've also read the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) exhaustively, searching for answers to what I consider a very basic requirement.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to modularize my code and create a small plugin to upload/select new background images for when I decide I want to change a given section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the image inline and then use advanced custom fields or something similar to add the image via the administration, like this:

```
<section class="section-1"
style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>');">
</section>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use PHP in custom fields. Otherwise, this would be perfect.

Comment: What do you mean? I've tried this and it works just fine. I don't know if it's the best approach though. Have you checked out [Acf](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) ?

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant. I was attempting to put the PHP inside of the actual custom fields in the Wordpress administration pages. It does work just fine. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I guess my answer could've been a little longer and more developed, good thing you figured it out!